# Can I replace a Racket's function with my custom function of the same name? Doable?

Tags: function, scheme, racket, metaprogramming

In the following code I defined my own `a-hl` with which I mean to replace the direct
call of `append` in my code. It does not really replace it as it uses append under the hood (see the comment):

```
#!/usr/bin/env racket
#lang racket/base

(require racket/file)

(define (a-hl l e) (append l (list e)))  
(define content (list "https://youtu.be/FVaVLpSHw38 Road to the Arnold" "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hlTfA42b_uI MIT Bitcoin Expo 2022: Breaking Through - Lightning Panel"))
(define arr (list))
(for ((l content)) 
  ;(set! arr (append arr (list (regexp-replace* #rx" .*" l "")))))
  (set! arr (a-hl arr (regexp-replace* #rx" .*" l "")))); works just as well but it is shorter
  
(for ((e arr)) (display e))
```

The code works fine. But when I attempt to define my own `append`, `(define (append l e) (append l (list e)))` and that use it,

```
(for ((l content)) 
  (set! arr (append arr (regexp-replace* #rx" .*" l ""))))
  
(for ((e arr)) (display e))
```

Racket freezes. Is it at all doable to replace a Racket's function with my custom function of the same name?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use Racket's `require`'s [`only-in`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/require.html#%28form._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Fbase..rkt%29._only-in%29%29) clause to give your own name to a binding from a module, and use that:

```lisp
#lang racket

(require (only-in racket/base [append builtin-append]))
(define (append l e) (builtin-append l (list e)))
(writeln (append '(1 2 3) 4)) ; (1 2 3 4)
```

or use `local-require` to import it only inside your function:

```lisp
(define (append l e)
  (local-require (only-in racket/base [append builtin-append]))
  (builtin-append l (list e)))
```

Answer (score 4):

You can define your own versions of functions, and doing that only affects code in your module or modules which `require` that definition from it.

Whether you *should* do that for definitions like `append`, is a different question: doing so is a good way of setting snares and traps for the unwary.  Probably it is something to do only if you really understand the consequences of doing it and if you are in the process of building a language which is semantically very different than the standard Racket languages.

In this case it looks like the unwary person caught in the trap was you.  Your definition of `append` is:

```
(define (append l e)
  (append l (list e)))
```

That is a definition which will clearly both not terminate, and use unbounded memory in the process of not terminating.

Your problem seems to be that you think that the version of `append` *called* by the definition is Racket's one.  It's not: that's not how `define` works, not in this case and not ever.  In a form like

```
(define (<name> ...)
  ... <name> ...)
```

or equivalently

```
(define <name>
  (lambda (...) ... <name> ...))
```

Then (assuming there are no intervening bindings of `<name>`), `<name>` refers to the thing you are defining.

Comment: Thanks. I've tried to use `let` to solve this problem: `(define (a-hl l e)(append l (list e)))`
`(define (append l e)(let ((append a-hl))(a-hl l e)))` but this falls as well in the trap of recursion. How might I then define my own `append` that uses Racket's `append` without falling into the 
trap of recursion?

Comment: @JohnSmith Your `let` cannot be in the function body since when that is runningf `append` is already been taken over by your function.. You need to use lambda. eg `(define append (let ((rappend append)) (lambda (l e) (rappend l (list e)))))` so you in your function have a name bound to what was `append`

Comment: @Sylwester: that won't work in Racket, because it treats `define` like some kind of implicit `letrec`: you'll get an 'attempt to refer to identifier before it is defined' error.  Shawn's answer – renaming on require – is the right one.  OTOH redefining `append` like this is just a horrible, horrible idea: just use another name.

Comment: @ignisvolens Interesting. They must have changed this as I cannot recall not being able to do this at least with the report languages, but I can confirm it doesn't work even in `#lang r5rs` and it did so before.

Comment: @Sylwester: it's  very desirable, as it means that a compiler can know that `append` is Racket's `append` and not some other random thing.